# AES Key Generation?

Tags: encryption

I am generating a random number and using the random am generating the AES key of 256 bit. If I use the same random number again, whether it will generate the same AES Key again ?
If not means why ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If thats the only source of random entropy then, of course it would generate the same key.

Answer (score 0):

I have only used PBKDF2 and it generates the same key every time. I think that as long as you use the same key derivation function with the same parameters every time (like the random number in this case), it will. I suggest you to read a bit about the key derivation function you are using.